# Nativescript VideoRecorder

Tags: nativescript

Just wondering why Nativescript haven't developed a Video recorder plugin as they have done with the Nativesckipt-Camera plugin or why in fact the camera plugin does not do video as well. I know there are options out there such as Nativescript-videorecorder, but seems to be an obvious omission of standard plugins for Nativescript.

Comment: You can try : https://github.com/jibon57/nativescript-mediafilepicker

Answer (score 2):

The NativeScript plugin for video recording is named `nativescript-videorecorder`. You can find it on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-videorecorder), [github](https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-videorecorder), or the [NativeScript marketplace](https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-videorecorder).

Make it available for use in your project by running the following command:

```
tns add plugin nativescript-videorecorder
```

Comment: Yes I've tried that, but having issues with iOS. I'm using JS core and not Typescript so struggling to implement this plugin. I've tried recoding the TS examples, but its crashing out. I'm getting the following error:- CONSOLE WARN file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-videorecorder/videorecorder.js:81:14: Objective-C class name "UIImagePickerControllerDelegateImpl" is already in use - using "UIImagePickerControllerDelegateImpl1" instead.
***** Fatal JavaScript exception - application has been terminated. *****

Comment: which version of nativescript-videorecorder are you using? Have you tried with 3.0.0-alpha.11 ? Also could you share your {NS} version?

Comment: Also try downgrading your NS to "version": "4.1.0"

Comment: I cannot downgrade NS to 4.1.0 because of other requirements. I'm running NS 5.0.1 at the moment. Are you saying that this plugin is not compatible with this version.

Comment: What you have pasted above is just a warning, the actual description of fatal JS exception seems missing. Can you post the complete error log?